# How to check/set "kernel timezone" for use with iptables "time" module?

Tags: kernel, linux-kernel, iptables, timezone

The `iptables -m time` module supports time-based firewall rules. By default it operates in UTC but with `--kerneltz` parameter it should work in "kernel timezone":

```
$ iptables -m time --help
    --kerneltz           Work with the kernel timezone instead of UTC
```

How do I check/set the kernel timezone? It seems to be 1 hour off from my system timezone (DST vs non-DST?). I would like to set the kernel timezone to match the system TZ, or at least check what it is.